# Checking if Play tag has a body

Tags: tags, playframework, conditional-statements

From the [docs](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/templates#Invoketagbody), you can pass a body to a tag like this:

```
#{hello}Bob#{/hello}
```

and the body can be used via `doBody`:

```
Hello #{doBody /}!
```

but how can you test whether or not a body was provided?

I want to do something like this in the tag:

```
#{if hasBody()}
    #{doBody /}
#{/if}
#{else}
    &{'pages.' + _arg + '.name'}
#{/else}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to keep your tag in html / tag format then you can use this syntax

```
#{if (s = play.templates.JavaExtensions.toString(_body).trim()) != ''}
  it has a body! ${s}
#{/if}
#{else}
  no body!!!!
#{/else}
```

Your other option is to use fastTags (see [this](http://playframework.wordpress.com/2010/11/26/fasttags-in-play/) blog post here) . In there you can essentially do the same thing

```
public static void _myTag(Map<?, ?> args, Closure body, PrintWriter out,  ExecutableTemplate template, int fromLine) {
  String s = JavaExtensions.toString(body);
  if (s.trim() != "" ) {
    //there is a body
  } else {
    // there is no body
  }
}
```

Comment: Got me on the right track but I had to rearrange things a bit--see my answer for details.

Comment: very strange, I tested that and was working... main thing is you got it sorted anyway

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to like `_body` inside the `if` tag; it causes a null pointer error. I worked around by moving it into a groovy block, so now my template looks like this:

```
%{
body = _body == null ? null : play.templates.JavaExtensions.toString(_body).trim();
}%
#{if body}
    #{doBody /}
#{/if}
#{else}
    ...
#{/else}
```